# Object Too Deep for Desired Array - scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint

I've just started with Python yesterday, and I'm getting an error using `scipy.integrate.odeint`.

I've defined a function

```
def SIR(x, t, beta, gamma, mu, M):
```

which takes the `numpy.array` objects `x`, `t`, and `M`; and the scalar floats `beta`, `gamma`, and `mu`.

`M` is `(60,60)` in size, but I don't think this matters.

`x` and `t` are both nonsingleton, with `x.shape` being `(180,)` and `t.shape` being `(5000,)`. I've tried giving them a singleton dimension, such that they have shapes `(180,1)` and `(5000,1)` respectively, but I still get the same error :

```
In [1]: run measles_age.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/qcaudron/Documents/SIR/measles_age.py in <module>()
    111 
    112 
--> 113         x = integrate.odeint(SIR, x0, t, args=(beta, gamma, mu, M));
    114 
    115 #       plot(t, x);


/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg)
    141     output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    142                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
--> 143                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
    144     if output[-1] < 0:
    145         print _msgs[output[-1]]
```

I get this error even when `SIR` just returns `x`, and if I strip all arguments apart from `x` and `t` from it :

```
def SIR(x, t):
    return x;
```

As you can see, the line causing the error is

```
x = integrate.odeint(SIR, x0, t, args=(beta, gamma, mu, M));
```

EDIT :

I've been asked to add the full code for the `SIR` method. Because it's relatively long, I've dropped the full .py script in a pastebin :
http://pastebin.com/RphJbCHN

Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to python!  Most of those semicolons are unnecessary in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware they're unnecessary - I just think things looks cleaner with them :) Thanks for the edit above.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), `SIR` should return `dx/dt` at `t`.  Is that what `SIR` does?

Comment: Yes, in the full code, it does. Where it returns `x` immediately, it's not really relevant - the equation we're solving could well be `dx/dt = x`, in which case, yes, it's returning the correct calculation. I'm not sure why an "object is too deep for desired array" error is being returned.

Comment: The [source is in `fortran`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.11.0/scipy/integrate/odepack/lsoda.f).  Have you tried using [`integrate.ode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html)?

Comment: In your stripped down case, the signature of `SIR` must be `SIR(x, t)`.  The `t` argument is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your error in several ways.

The error occurs immediately if either the `y0` argument or the `t` argument to `odeint` is not a 1-D array.  In the code example posted on pastebin (referred to in a comment), `t` is reshaped like this:

```
t = np.arange(0, 520, 1);
t = t.reshape(len(t),1);
```

Delete the line that reshapes `t`.  `t` must be a 1-D array, not a 2-D array with shape (len(t), 1).

For example...

```
In [177]: def SIR(x, t):
   .....:     return x
   .....:
```

This works...

```
In [178]: x0 = [0.1, 0.2]

In [179]: odeint(SIR, x0, t=[0, 0.5, 1])
Out[179]: 
array([[ 0.1       ,  0.2       ],
       [ 0.16487213,  0.32974426],
       [ 0.27182822,  0.54365643]])
```

This results in the error:

```
In [180]: x0 = [[0.1, 0.2]]  # wrong shape

In [181]: odeint(SIR, x0, t=[0, 0.5, 1])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-181-a37878f92395> in <module>()
----> 1 odeint(SIR, x0, t=[0, 0.5, 1])

/home/warren/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.pyc in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg)
    142     output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    143                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
--> 144                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
    145     if output[-1] < 0:
    146         print _msgs[output[-1]]

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Check that the initial condition that you give to `odeint` (the second argument) is a *1-D* numpy array (not a 2-D array with shape (1, 180) or (180, 1)).

I also get the 'object too deep...' error if `SIR` *returns* an array with the wrong shape.  It must return a *1-D* array, with the same shape as its first argument.  Make sure it is truly 1-D, and not 2-D with shape (1, 180) or (180, 1).

Comment: Thank you - however, I've checked this. `SIR` returns a numpy array `(180,)` in size, and the `y0` argument to `odeint` is also `(180,)` in shape.

Comment: @Quentin: If you can, please add your code for SIR to the question, along with a self-contained way of running it, so we can reproduce the error you get.

Comment: I updated my answer with a comment about `t` being 1-D.  Don't reshape it to be a 2-D array.

Comment: Thank you so much, Warren. I don't know how I missed that. I fixed this, and it seems to run.

Answer (score -1):

From the [tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#ordinary-differential-equations-odeint) it looks like the first argument to `integrate.odeint()` needs to be a function to operate on (in your case) `x0` and `t`. Since your `SIR()` function only takes one argument, the operation is failing. It's possible that the size and/or shape of the results returned from `SIR()` are important in relation to the rest of the arguments.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. I stripped it to just that to see if the problem was the `SIR` function. It wasn't. I got the same error as when `SIR` took five arguments :

    `def SIR(x, t, beta, gamma, mu):`     
        `return x;`

and was called using

    `x = integrate.odeint(SIR, x0, t, args=(beta, gamma, mu));`