# ValueError and odepack.error using integrate.odeint()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, odeint

I'm trying to write an equation to model and then plot an integral control system (specifically regarding cruise control). However I'm receiving two errors whenever I run it:

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
odepack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.

I've read these questions:

- [scipy curve_fit error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184541/scipy-curve-fit-error-result-from-function-call-is-not-a-proper-array-of-floats)
- [How to solve this differential equation using scipy odeint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019427/how-to-solve-this-differential-equation-using-scipy-odeint)
- [Object Too Deep for Desired Array - scipy.integrate.odeint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709933/object-too-deep-for-desired-array-scipy-integrate-odeint)

Which seem like they should be helpful, however I'm unsure how to apply those to my problem.  I'm fairly new to python so please bear with me if I've missed something obvious or done something exceptionally silly.  I have no problems with plotting it, so once I figure out how to actually get this working I think I'm set.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

##Parameters

kp=.5 #proportional gain
ki=.1 #integral gain
vr=30 #desired velocity in m/s
Tm=190 #Max Torque in Nm
wm=420 #engine speed
B=0.4 #Beta
an=12 #at gear 4
p=1.3 #air density
Cd=0.32 #Drag coefficient
Cr=.01 #Coefficient of rolling friction
A=2.4 #frontal area

##Variables

m=18000 #weight
v=20 #starting velocity
time=np.linspace(0,10,50) #time
theta=np.radians(4) #Theta

def vderivs(state,t):
    v = state
    vel=[]
    ti=0

    while ti < t:
        v1 = an*controller(ti,vr,v)*torque(v)
        v2 = m*Cr*np.sign(v)
        v3 = 0.5*p*Cd*A*v**2
        v4 = m*np.sin(theta)

        if t < 10:
            vtot = v1+v2+v3
            vfin = np.divide(vtot,m)
        else:
            vtot = v1+v2+v3+v4
            vfin = np.divide(vtot,m)

        vel.append(vfin)
        ti+=1

    trueVel = np.array(vel, float)
    return trueVel

def uderivs(state,t):
    v = state
    deltax = vr - v
    return deltax    

def controller(time,desired,currentV):
    z = integrate.odeint(uderivs, currentV, time)
    u = kp*(vr-currentV)+ki*z
    return u.flatten()

def torque(v):    
    return Tm*(1-B*(np.divide(an*v,wm)-1)**2)   

def velocity(mass,desired,theta,t):
    v = integrate.odeint(vderivs, desired, t)
    return v.flatten()

test = velocity(m,vr,theta,time)
print(test)
```

Please let me know if there is anything else you need from me!

Comment: Can you post a snippet of related code here? That might help

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean? The exact code I'm using is in the post and also here http://pastebin.com/5pubqMg1

Comment: Don't paste it in the pastebin, as it may get deleted or broken. Just paste the relevant part here.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry. Updated question with the code, included it in its entirety as I'm not positive what is causing the issue.

Comment: `vderivs(state, t)` doesn't depend on `t`... should it?

Comment: It probably should, but when I was previously testing the code it wouldn't iterate over t like I needed it to.  Removing t outright caused problems though, so I just ignored it and redefined it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your structure will work, because of how each integration depends on the other integration.  Also, you seem to expect `controller` to take one value of `t`, but `controller` is just a wrapper for `odeint` which expects `t` to be an array of all values of time over which to integrate but you call it within `vderivs` with just a scalar for `t`.  You might be able to fix this just by vectorizing `vderivs` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah that is what I realized when I started having errors.  Integral control systems are supposed to take their own output, compare it to the expected/desired output, and then take that error and input them into themselves.  I tried to deal with this as best I can, but as you can see it didn't work well.  I've also been thinking that implementing it with a delay (which is more realistic anyway) might solve the issue, however bring delay into it opens its own can of worms... When you say vectorizing vderivs what do you mean by that?

Comment: Yes but an integral control system integrates up to the current time, but your code requests integration over all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as separate, because I got your code to work.  Well, to run and produce output :P

Actually one big problem is some stealth broadcasting that I didn't notice, but I changed a lot of other things along the way.

First the stealth broadcasting is that if you integrate a 1d function with one parameter, `odeint` returns a column vector, and then when you do stuff with that result that is a row vector, then you get a 2d array (matrix).  For example:

```
In [704]: a
Out[704]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [705]: b
Out[705]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [706]: a+b
Out[706]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

You were getting output for velocity that was a column vector like `b` and adding it to some other function of time, and getting a matrix.

---

With regards to the recursion, I think I sovled that issue.  The two derivative functions should take a single scalar `t` at which point they calculate the derivative.  To do that, `vderivs` needs to do the integral, which it should do over all time up to `t`.  So I redefined them as such:

```
dt = .1   # another global constant parameter

def vderivs(v, t):
    ts = np.arange(0, t, dt)
    v1 = an * controller(v, ts) * torque(v)
    v2 = m*Cr*np.sign(v)
    v3 = 0.5*p*Cd*A*v**2 
    v4 = m*np.sin(theta)
    vtot = v1+v2+v3+v4*(ts>=10) # a vector of times includes incline only after ts = 10
    return vtot/m
```

And of course `uderivs` is fine as is but can be written more simply:

```
def uderivs(v, t):
    return vr - v
```

Then, make sure that `velocity` and `controller` pass the right values (using `v0` instead of `v` for the starting velocity):

```
def controller(currentV, time):
    z = integrate.odeint(uderivs, currentV, time)
    return kp*(vr-currentV) + ki*z.squeeze()

def velocity(desired, theta, time):
    return integrate.odeint(vderivs, desired, time)
```

Who knows if the physics is correct, but this gives:

[image: short time]

Note that it hasn't reached the desired velocity, so I increased the time over which it was to be solved

```
time = np.linspace(0,50,50) #time
```

[image: long time]

Here is all the code that I ran:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

##Parameters
kp = .5 #proportional gain
ki = .1 #integral gain
vr = 30 #desired velocity in m/s
Tm = 190 #Max Torque in Nm
wm = 420 #engine speed
B = 0.4 #Beta
an = 12 #at gear 4
p = 1.3 #air density
Cd = 0.32 #Drag coefficient
Cr = .01 #Coefficient of rolling friction
A = 2.4 #frontal area

##Variables
m = 18000.0 #weight
v0 = 20. #starting velocity
t = np.linspace(0, 20, 50) #time
dt = .1
theta = np.radians(4) #Theta

def torque(v):    
    return Tm * (1 - B*(an*v/wm - 1)**2)  

def vderivs(v, t):
    ts = np.arange(0, t, dt)
    v1 = an * controller(v, ts) * torque(v)
    v2 = m*Cr*np.sign(v)
    v3 = 0.5*p*Cd*A*v**2
    v4 = m*np.sin(theta)
    vtot = v1+v2+v3+v4*(ts>=10)
    return vtot/m

def uderivs(v, t):
    return vr - v

def controller(currentV, time):
    z = integrate.odeint(uderivs, currentV, time)
    return kp*(vr-currentV) + ki*z.squeeze()

def velocity(desired, theta, time):
    return integrate.odeint(vderivs, desired, time)

plt.plot(t, velocity(v0, theta, t), 'k-', lw=2, label='velocity')
plt.plot(t, controller(v0, t), 'r', lw=2, label='controller')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well I'm no longer getting an error, and sometimes it appears to be doing something, but it keeps getting caught in a loop in uderivs().  Any idea of the cause?  I'm copy/pasting directly from what you wrote here

Comment: @Dannnno, I'm not sure what would cause that, the code runs fine on my computer.

Comment: I found the issue, my computer didn't seem to like ts.  Removing that makes it work find, thank you!

Comment: I've never heard of that.  Do you know what it didn't like about it?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  The only thing I can think of is that it was making a matrix or something by using the earlier time = np.linspace(0,20,50) when forming ts = np.arange(0,t,dt)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but a few comments on your code that I've noticed.

As @qmorgan points out, you've named a parameter in your `controller` function the same as another function: `velocity`  Try to be consistent in your variable names to avoid such things.  For example, all of your constants are short abbreviations.  So, when you name parameters in functions, perhaps use words, this way you'll have a habit of knowing where you've used what.

You've made a few similar mistakes where you have a parameter for something in your function but you ignore it in the body of the function, and instead use a constant.  For example, you've defined `velocity` to take `(mass, desired, theta, t)` but you pass it `(m, v, theta, time)` where `v` is your *starting* velocity.  Be careful!  You didn't notice this mistake because in fact, `velocity` *ignores* `desired` and instead just uses `vr` the global constant.  Instead, this whole bit should have something like

```
def velocity(mass, desired, theta, t):
    return integrate.odeint(vderivs, desired, t)

plt.plot(time, velocity(m, vr, theta, time), 'k-')
```

---

To convert a list to a numpy array, you can just use `np.array(vel, float)` instead of `np.array([x for x in vel], float)` since `[x for x in vel]` is identical to `vel` itself.

---

In `vderivs` your loop through `t` can *probably* be completely eliminated, but at the very least I think it should be something more like:

```
ti = 0
while ti < t:
    ...
    ti += 1
```

Which doesn't ignore the input `t`.

---

As it stands now, `uderivs` takes a current velocity and a globally defined desired velocity and returns their difference:

```
def uderivs(v, t):  
    return vr - v
```

But you always pass it `vr` (see definition of `controller`), so every time you integrate it, it will simply return a flat array of length `t.size` and value `vr`.

---

Instead of `theta = 4` you probably want `theta = np.radians(4)`

---

There exists already in numpy the function `np.sign`, no need to implement your own.

Comment: Ok so I made the changes you recommended, except for the part about passing uderivs vr.  I'm not sure how I'd pass it the actual current velocity since the current velocity is dependent on the controller.  Should I try to implement some sort of delay, and if so where should that go?  I was thinking if I can generate initial conditions of some kind in the vderivs function then this would work better, I'm just unsure of how to approach it.  Also, why would the loop in vderivs be unnecessary? The goal was to make a 'before incline' and 'after incline' sort of situation.

Answer (score -1):

One error that I see is in the function `controller`; you are trying to subtract a function (`velocity`) from an integer (`vr`) which is likely the source of some of the problem.

The "object too deep for desired array" errors are probably coming from a separate issue where the returns from the functions `controller` and `velocity` are of the wrong shape; they need to be 1-d numpy arrays. You can fix this using the `flatten()` method:

```
In [82]: z.shape
Out[82]: (50, 1)

In [83]: z_flat=z.flatten()

In [84]: z_flat.shape
Out[84]: (50,)
```

But in order to fully debug, you need to fix the above error in the controller function.

Comment: Actually `velocity` is a parameter name for the function `controller`.  This is poor practice, but not a bug.

Comment: Like askewchan said, that wasn't using the function velocity but rather a variable named velocity. It has since been renamed currentV.  I have also added the .flatten() but the same error is occurring.  The question has been edited to reflect these things.